# OpenGL integer texture raising GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an Nvidia GTX 970, with the latest (441.66) driver for Win 10 x64 (18362 build), which is obviously fully OpenGL 4.6 compliant, and currently compiling an app with VS2017.

My problem is, that I seem to be unable to use any other texture type then `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. I'm currently trying to set up a single channel, unsigned integer (32 bit) texture, but however I try to allocate the texture, OpenGL immediately raises the `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error, and the shader's result turns all black.

So far I tryed allocating immutably:
`glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, 3072, 2048);`

And mutably:
`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, 3072, 2048, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, textureData);`

I tried signed int too, the same thing. I also checked with NSight VS edition, for UINT 2D textures, my max resolution is 16384x16384, so that's not the issue. Also, according to NSight, uint textures are fully supported by the OpenGL driver.

What am I missing here?

Minimum reproducable version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>

void OGLErrorCheck()
{
    const GLenum errorCode = glGetError();
    if (errorCode != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        const GLubyte* const errorString = gluErrorString(errorCode);
        std::cout << errorString;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    glewInit();
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, 3072, 2048, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    OGLErrorCheck();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This yields `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.
This is linked with the latest SDL and GLEW, both free software, available for download at https://www.libsdl.org/ and http://glew.sourceforge.net/ respectively.

Comment: You have to show a [mcve] for `glTexImage2D`, with all parts of your texture setup until the error occurs, including how you detect that error.

Comment: That's not really a [mcve]. Let's just ignore that there is no context creation and activation here, but I don't see any texture generation and binding in your example.

Answer (score 3):

From the specs about [glTexStorage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml):

> ```
> void glTexStorage2D(    
>     GLenum target,
>     GLsizei levels,
>     GLenum internalformat,
>     GLsizei width,
>     GLsizei height
> );
> ```
>
> […]
>    `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated if `width`, `height` or **`levels`** are less than 1

And the value for `levels` you pass to `glTexStorage2D` is `0`.

Comment: True, damn, I figured 0 would turn off mipmapping entirely, which worked for glTexImage2D.

Anyways, I'm still in trouble, cause I can't upload the data. If I glTexSubImage2D after the glTexStorage2D call, I get a GL_INVALID_OPERATION, as per specification. However, glTexImage2D still doesn't work with GL_UNSIGNED_INT. Spec says 0 level is OK for glTexImage2D.

Comment: @CivDav the point of my comment to your question ist still true. Without a [mcve] showing the whole process of texture setup and how you detect that error, it is not possible to tell. And additional questions like regarding  `glTexSubImage2D` should be asked in a new distinct question because it is a different problem. It is not a forum, but a Q&A platform, so you have to use it according to this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to create an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). e.g.:
(See also [Using OpenGL With SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html))

```cpp
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    return 0;

SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("ogl wnd", 0, 0, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
if (window == nullptr)
    return 0;
SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    return 0;
```

Then you have to generate an texture name by [`glGenTextures`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenTextures.xhtml):

```cpp
GLuint tobj;
glGenTextures(1, &tobj);
```

After that you've to bind the named texture to a texturing target by [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml):

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tobj);
```

Finally you can specify the two-dimensional texture image by [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, 3072, 2048, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

Note, the texture format has to be `GL_RED_INTEGER` rather than `GL_RED`, because the source texture image has to be interpreted as integral data, rather than normalized floating point data. The *format* and *type* parameter specify the format of the source data. The *internalformat* parameter specifies the format of the target texture image.

Set the texture parameters by [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) ( this can be done before `glTexImage2D`, too):

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

If you do not generate [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (by [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)), then setting the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is important. Since the default filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` the texture would be mipmap incomplete, if you don not change the minifying function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

Comment: "*`GL_RED`*" You mean `GL_RED_INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

> And mutably: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, 3072, 2048, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, textureData);
>
> I tried signed int too, the same thing. I also checked with NSight VS edition, for `UINT` 2D textures, my max resolution is 16384x16384, so that's not the issue. Also, according to NSight, `uint` textures are fully supported by the OpenGL driver.
>
> What am I missing here?

For unormalized integer texture formatss, the `format` parameter of `glTex[Sub]Image` is not allowed to be just `GL_RED`, you have to use `GL_RED_INTEGER`.The `format,type` combination `GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT` is for specifying normalized fixed point or floating point formats only.